# MySQL and PHP print the highest date based on function inside a while loop

Tags: php, mysql, function, date, loops

I print rows from `MySQL` in a `loop` like this:

```
$list_students = mysql_query(
"SELECT 
    s.student_id, s.student_firstname, s.student_lastname, s.isActive, 
    c.city_name,
    sd.student_startdate, sd.student_enddate
        FROM students s 
            INNER JOIN cityselections c ON c.city_id = s.student_city_id
            INNER JOIN studentdates sd ON sd.student_id = s.student_id
                WHERE s.student_city_id NOT LIKE '1'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($list_students)) 
{
    echo "<tr>\n";
        echo "<td>" . $row['student_lastname'] . ",  " . $row['student_firstname'] ."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>" . $row['student_startdate'] . "</td>\n";
        echo "<td>" . $row['student_enddate'] . "</td>\n";          
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

I also have this `function`:

```
function calculateNextDate($startDate, $days)
{
        $dateTime = new DateTime($startDate);

        while($days) {
            $dateTime->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));    

            if ($dateTime->format('N') < 6) {
                $days--;
            }
        }

        return $dateTime->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Wich calculates a date, given a startdate and number and excludes weekends. For example:

```
calculateNextDate ($list_students['student_startdate'],15)
```

Now I would like this function to work inside the while loop, using another `MySQL`- query **that could return multiple rows for each `student_id`**:

```
SELECT scp.cpl_id, scp.student_id, SUM(scpe.scpe_estimated_days) AS total FROM studentcourseplan scp
    INNER JOIN studentcourseplanelements scpe ON scpe.scpe_cpl_id = scp.cpl_id
            GROUP BY scp.cpl_id
```

This could output:

```
+--------+------------+-------+
| cpl_id | student_id | total |
+--------+------------+-------+
|    195 |         34 |    74 |
|    204 |         85 |   153 |
|    205 |         85 |   199 |
|    206 |         65 |    11 |
+--------+------------+-------+
```

**I need the function to calculate the highest number of the output inside the `loop` and print the date this outputs**

.. for each student (`student_id`).

How can this be done?

Comment: "[..]that could return multiple rows:[..]": Uh.. What? Why would it *not* return multiple rows?

Comment: Thank's for pointing that out. Corrected.

Comment: I think some examples might help.

Comment: A simple 'SELECT *' from whatever table $list_students come from would help immensely.

Comment: @MarcusHansson see code update